# How can I upgrade "accentColor" in "ThemeData" in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, syntax, upgrade, themedata

I got the following code:

```
  theme: ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.purple,
    accentColor: Colors.deepOrange,
    fontFamily: 'Lato',
    pageTransitionsTheme: PageTransitionsTheme(
      builders: {
        TargetPlatform.android: CustomPageTransitionBuilder(),
        TargetPlatform.iOS: CustomPageTransitionBuilder(),
      },
    ),
  ),
```

And I know the `accentColor` is deprecated, so because of that I get the following errors for these lines of code:

```
 TextStyle( color: Theme.of(context).accentTextTheme.title.color,),
```

> The getter 'title' isn't defined for the type 'TextTheme'. Try
> importing the library that defines 'title', correcting the name to the
> name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named
> 'title'.

```
 TextStyle( color: Theme.of(context).primaryTextTheme.title.color,),
```

> The getter 'title' isn't defined for the type 'TextTheme'. Try
> importing the library that defines 'title', correcting the name to the
> name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named
> 'title'.

How can I fix the issue and upgrade the codes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of `accentColor`, use `colorScheme`:

```dart
colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch(primarySwatch: Colors.purple)
            .copyWith(secondary: Colors.deepOrange),
```

Usage:

```
Color myColor = Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary;
```

#### See also

- [ThemeData's accent properties have been deprecated](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/theme-data-accent-properties#migration-guide)
- [ThemeData (the docs)](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeData-class.html)

---

If you're using Android Studio, you can right-click on the deprecated warning for it to fix the error:

[image]